# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 3^{\sqrt{n}}}$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Is   $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 3^{\sqrt{n}}}$ convergent ?

I use it to compare with $1/n^2$, and then I used LHôpitals rule multiple times. Finally , I can solve it. However,I think we have other methods!  somebody can help me?

Comment: Check this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty+%7B1%5Cover+3%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7Bn%7D%7D%7D&dataset=

Comment: ye,but how to prove it without using computer?

Comment: Your argument seems reasonably simple. You basically want to show that $\frac{x^4}{c^x}$ approaches $0$, where $c\gt 1$. Write $c^x$ as $e^{x\ln c}$ and apply L'Hospital's Rule. True, we need to do it in principle $4$ times, but after the first time the rest is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $$k\le\sqrt{n}< k+1$$ then, since the function $x\mapsto 3^x$ is increasing, we have $$3^k\le3^{\sqrt{n}}<3^{k+1},\;\;\text{and}$$ $$\frac{1}{3^k}\ge\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}>\frac{1}{3^{k+1}}$$for every $n\in [k^2,(k+1)^2[$ then 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{N^2-1}{\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}} & = \frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{2}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{3}}}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\ldots+\underbrace{\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{(N-1)^2}}}+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{(N-1)^2+1}}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{N^2-1}}}}_{2N-1\,\text{terms}}\\
& \le \frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\ldots+\underbrace{\frac{1}{3^{N-1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{3^{N-1}}}_{2N-1\;\text{terms}}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{N-1}{\frac{2k+1}{3^k}}
\end{align}
Then, for comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}}}$ converges if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{2k+1}{3^k}}$ does, and this happens due the ratio test.

Answer (score 5):

You can group entries according to $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ and bound the sum from above:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1} \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{n}}} \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k+1}{3^k} = 2$$
Since your sequence consists of positive numbers only, this implies its convergence.

Comment: Simple and elegant. I like it!

Comment: Very nice and witty answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

You can prove that: $3^{\sqrt{n}} > n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ for large enough $n$ and this inequality comes from: $3^x > x^3$ is true for all $x > 4$ especially integer value $x$. From this you can readily use the comparison test. In fact, you can make it a bit stronger.... because $3^x > x^k$ for a given positive $k$

Comment: But  $3^{\sqrt{n}} > n^{\frac{3}{2}}$ does not mean $3^x>x^3$, it means $ 3^{2\sqrt{n}}>n^3$

Comment: @tiandiao123 No, $3^{\sqrt{n}}>(\sqrt{n})^3$ becomes $3^x>x^3$ when $x=\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence):

The function $\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{x}}}$ is continuous, positive and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. We then evaluate the integral:

\begin{align}
\int_1^\infty\, \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{x}}}\, dx = \frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)} + \frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)^{2}} \approx 1.15918311754471
\end{align}

and see that it has a finite value, which in turn proves that the sum is also finite.

It can also be used to get the lower and upper bounds:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 3^{\sqrt{n}}} &\ge \int_1^\infty\, \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{x}}}\, dx\\
&\ge \frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)} + \frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)^{2}} \approx 1.15918311754471
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 3^{\sqrt{n}}} &\le \frac{1}{3}+\int_1^\infty\, \frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{x}}}\, dx\\
&\le \frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)} + \frac{2}{3 \, \log\left(3\right)^{2}} \approx 1.49251645087804
\end{align}

The actual numerical result using a program:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over 3^{\sqrt{n}}} \approx 1.34070489742952420178654874099073605072839417287611074076358138561327
\end{align}

p.s. the integral can be easily solved by observing that $3^\sqrt{x} = e^{\left(\sqrt{x} \ln\left(3\right)\right)}$

Comment: I don't get it: you showed the series is greater than or equal a finite number. How does this help to decide whether or not the series converges?

Comment: Hi, it's one of the standard tests for convergence which can also be used for finding upper and lower bounds. See the [integral test wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

Comment: No @gar, it is not. I think you're confusing things here...What you did is *neither* the integral test nor the comparison one or anything of the like that can help to decide whether the series converges or not.

Comment: Then what is the integral test? Using the information in that wiki entry I get the lower and upper bounds of about 1.15918 and 1.49251 respectively, which agrees..

Comment: The integral test says that if you have a positive monotonically-descending function $\;f(n)\;$ that converges to zero as $\;n\to\infty\;$ , then $\;\int f(x)\,dx\;$ converges iff $\;\sum f(n)\;$ converges. You can read it here : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegralTest.html ...and you showed a lower bound for the series (assuming that integral there indeed equals what you wrote), but *not* an upper bound, which is what **really matters** for positive series...

Comment: Bounds are not of actual importance here, I just showed it as an example. The function $\frac{1}{3^{\sqrt{x}}}$ is continuous, positive and decreasing on $[1,\infty)$. If the integral is convergent, sum is convergent as well; that's what matters.

Comment: No @gar, what matters is to address the OP's question, which is whether the series converges or not. You didn't show this.

Comment: @DonAntonio : Check out some [examples](https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/Calculus/Section_8.3--The_Integral_and_Comparison_Tests/The_Integral_and_Comparison_Tests.pdf). We saw that the integral converges to a value, it *implies* that the sum converges as well.

Comment: I really can't understand why we're having this discussion...honestly. Can't you see you did **not** prove the given series *converges*? You didn't, period. It's not a matter of opinion. Why do you insist in arguing that showing that the series is **bigger** than a converging integral is showing the *series converges*?? This is just false! Or prove me wrong, of course. What you seem to be wanting to do is to argue that that integral converges (and you did NOT show this, you only bounded its value, again!, from below), and then use the integral test...do you see it?

Comment: Having a finite value for the integral *proves* the convergence of the sum. That's what the integral test is for as I understand it. Getting the bounds is not of importance here. It's not my opinion, it's the integral test. I have edited my answer, if you still insist it's incorrect, I'd like to learn what's the correct way to apply the integral test here or prove it can't be applied.

Comment: **I know** what you write in your first phrase ! But you:(1) did **not** give a value for the integral but a lower bound for it, and thus (2) you did not prove the integral converges, and thus the integral test is unappliable. But **now** it is finally fine...assuming the improper integral indeed equals that number you say. All the other calculations are fine but irrelevant for the OP's question, who could probably be interested in knowing how to prove that integral's value is what you wrote.

Comment: I **did** give the value of the integral, I only wanted to convey that the value can be used as the lower bound. No need to assume about the values I post, everything will be computer verified, numerically and symbolically. I like to do the extras, just posted so that somebody may find it useful. Anyway, thanks for letting me know about your doubt, and hope that it's clear enough to everyone now.

Comment: *Sigh*...ok. Anyway, the OP may be interested in something he can prove *by hand*, as most decent mathematics departments won't accept a proof based on something a machine calculated.

Comment: Okay, added a hint for solving the integral. While I agree that most mathematics exams do not allow computers, I reject that it's anything "decent"!

Comment: Your entitled to your opinion, @gar...but in my experience, *any* mathematics deparment (even in high school) is interested in their students' development of reasoning skills to deduce stuff, so if it were allowed to use calculators and computers, what's the point of asking "Prove that $\;\sum\frac1{n^2}\;$ converges" ? Just use your calculator and say "Hey! I got it: my Casio says the sum is $\;\frac{\pi^2}6\;$...so it converges!

Comment: Yeah, it's my opinion which most may not agree with. Evaluating directly is not what I mean by using computers. It's supposed to be used to get insightful hints, to provide the building blocks for a proof, instead of wasting time on mundane stuffs! Have a good day..